# GUI how to list available files on a server

Tags: java, user-interface

i am designing a file sharing application and at the application client level i want the client to be able to see all the files availble on the server , can you give me a way were i can use GUI components to list them ? am using socket programming this is my server code

Server Side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



class TCPServer {

    public static void listfile(){

    File folder = new File("c:/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
  }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        listfile();

        while (true) {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
            Socket connectionSocket = null;
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;

            try {
                welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
                connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }


            if (outToClient != null) {

                String FileName = "carexception.java";

                File myFile = new File("C:\\"+FileName);

                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = null;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                try {
                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.flush();
                    outToClient.close();
                    connectionSocket.close();

                    // File sent, exit the main method
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Client side

```
   import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    class TCPClient {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
            int bytesRead;

            Socket clientSocket = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3248);
                is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            if (is != null) {

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\sss.java");
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

                    do {
                            baos.write(aByte);
                            bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
                    } while (bytesRead != -1);

                    bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i wrote this code to project the files i have on the server availble

```
    public static void listfile(){

    File folder = new File("c:/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
  }
```

how can i project them into J tree or Jpanel ?

Comment: You could use a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or a [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Sorry I updated the code now ..

Comment: You REALLY need to send the list of results back to the client so the client can then decide how to present it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

1. Send list of available files in a selected folder to client and list those files using JTable or [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
2. When a file selection, If selected file is folder, get list of files for that folder and display it again
3. If selected file is a file, prompt save point location in client then save it.

Here is an example given for [TCP Chat Program](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~amyles/tutorials/tcpchat/) using swing you can modify this for file sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much i am going to study the code and see if it can be handy however i might come back for further questions ..